# Capistrano Multi-user Deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

We use Capistrano to deploy the changes to our website. Everything works perfectly, but I now have another staff member that is trained to deploy changes. Each time she deploys changes she has to change the deploy.rb file and change set:user to her (and vise vera). Is there a way in the code to use multiple users?

such as:
set:user user1 OR user2?

Since we use Github for our versioning control and we made it mandatory to comment on every change it cause a lot of extra steps.

Comment: can you use a common deploy user? and then each user that needs access  you just add their public keys to correct repos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to deploy app for multiple users, you can dynamically change username in deploy.rb file.

I'm not sure, if capistrano allows to do you out of the box, but you can drop a file, for example at your project root, or somewhere else, with just a username.

In deploy.rb

```
set :user, File.read('/path/to/file').strip
```

Keep in mind, that you should also add this file to .gitignore. So each developer should have its own file with deploy username.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to simply remove the username entirely. Then it should use your local username:

```
server 'myservername', roles: %w{web app db}
```

If the server username is different from your local username, try updating `~/.ssh/config` to specify the correct user.

```
Host myservername
  User user2
```